# what does "under no circumstances should you approach the man"?

Tags: meaning

"Under no circumstances should you approach the man".

This sentence has been taken from Cambridge Dictionary. To know the meaning of "approach" I searched in this dictionary and I found this sentence.

I cannot understand the meaning of it at all. It would be helpful if anybody like to rewrite it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's *a writing style.* The modal verb *'should'* is also used to *give an advice*.

Check the dictionary [OALD entry #2.](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/should?q=should)

> *used for giving or asking for advice.*

Rewriting is possible:

> You shouldn't approach the man under any circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

This phrase is commonly used in local news broadcasts in the United States to warn citizens to be on the lookout for a suspect who has committed a robbery or other violent crime. It is frequently followed by an additional warning and instructions, such as this:

> "Under no circumstances should you approach the suspect, who is believed to be armed and dangerous. If you see him, call the police department or Sheriff's Office immediately."